# How to set two different sound levels for two different sounds played simultaneously from two applications?

Tags: audio, volume-control, volume, mx-player

I'm using [Poweramp Music Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer) (in the background) to play music, and [MX Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad) (in the foreground) to play videos (video lectures). What I'm looking for is to play music in the background with a specific (low) sound level (or volume level) while playing videos in the foreground on MX Player with another (higher) sound level. I'm able to play two sounds simultaneously by disabling *Permanent Audio Focus Change* (in Audio Focus ← Audio in Poweramp, hinted by this [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/125250/how-to-have-two-applications-play-sound-simultaneously)) but without being able to set two different sound levels for the two sounds (The sound from Poweramp and the other one from MX Player) as there is only one generic sound level for everything on the media stream that all apps abide to.

How could I set **different sound levels** for two simultaneously played sounds from two different applications?

### Suggestions tried but unsuccessful:

- I've tried [App Volume Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spycorp.appvolumecontrolpro), but it says:

  > It's not possible to have a background app and a foreground app with different volumes, this is an Android limitation.

### Device Info:

ROM: Android v6.0.1 (Rooted with Xposed installed)

Comment: This might help, although I haven't tested it myself. https://fieldguide.gizmodo.com/set-different-volume-levels-for-each-app-on-your-androi-1756332280

Comment: @Frank12 I've tried App Volume Control, but it says:
It's not possible to have a background app and a foreground app with different volumes, this is an Android limitation.