# How can I prevent Microsoft Teams from muting my alarms?

Tags: audio, android-10, alarm, microsoft-teams

If I'm in a Microsoft teams meetings, my alarms are muted (the alarm shows up on the screen but the sound is barely audible). How can I prevent Microsoft Teams from muting my alarms?

I  use MS Teams on Android 10 with Samsung Galaxy S9.

Comment: Did you see/try: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/246776/3573 otherwise the topic is "Audio Focus"

Comment: Thanks, good to know about that term.