# Audio interrupted randomly (by other apps?)

Tags: audio

How can I prevent my audio playback from being interrupted?  Whatever is going on with other apps seems to very often stop my listening and I have to go and press play again.

Most specifically, I start audio playback, and then engage the Angry Birds Dream Blast or any of several games, or other apps. The audio gets interrupted and I have to stop everything and resume playback. I downloaded Permission Manager X, by Irfan Latif, but I can't see how it can help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I prevent an app from interrupting audio playback of some other app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/246764/44325)